# Is there a point to the naming tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Based on the [Are “name that thing” questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/are-name-that-thing-questions-on-topic) question I think [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) questions that don't qualify as [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) questions are off topic / too localised, and quite a few of them are closed as such.

- I can't find an example of an on topic [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) question that I wouldn't also consider a [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) question. Are there any?
- Can they be considered synonyms? I'd say not, but as a non native English speaker I'd like some back up.
- Should we try and clean up [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)? There are 133 questions currently and I think some minor clean up effort would be in order, even if only to re-tag some of those as [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) - happy to do it, in small steps, if I get some basic guidelines.

I've just removed [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) from [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126194/need-help-with-naming-marshaling-interface-calls), it felt more like a proper [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) question, to my mind [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is more serious and on topic than [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) and my edit may discourage less serious naming suggestions.

I'm not really sure if [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) should die, that's was my instictual reaction when I first stumbled upon it, but if there are reasons for it to stay hopefully we'll get a tag wiki for it out of this question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [naming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) should be cleaned up, with questions about words and phrases going into [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), questions about naming variables/methods/blocks going into [code-style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-style) or [code-quality](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-quality), and maybe a few other tags. I only looked at a couple of handfuls of questions tagged with naming, so there might be some other cleanups.