# Why don't we have a "General Refence" close reason? Can we get it?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would the “General Reference” close reason be useful here on Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/would-the-general-reference-close-reason-be-useful-here-on-programmers)

On Scifi.SE, they have a close reason "General Reference" that states "This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information."

I think this would be tremendously useful and a much better explanation for closing many of the "panic questions" and "help vampires" that pop up. Would it be possible for us to get such a thing? I can't count the number of times I've seen questions like this appear on Programmers.